# NodeJS backend is mixing up session data on concurrent requests

Tags: node.js, express, session, passport.js, tedious

I have developed a multiple user web application with Node js.
I used ExpresJS as framework and also used PassportJS to manage the authentication and user's sessions.

Everything is working ok but there is a big problem when two or more users make a concurrent request:

The backend is mixing the requests and returning wrong response to clients so they can get information of other users.

I do not know what is happening and I am having a very big pain. My code for passport serializing/deserializing (I am using a SQL Server Database and [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) to connect):

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done)=>{
    done(null, user.Id)
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done)=>{
    params = []
    db.buildParams(params,"Id", TYPES.Int, id)
    db.procedure("FindUserById", params, (rows)=>{
        console.log(rows[0])
        done(null, rows[0])
    })
})
```

My app configuration:

```
const app = express()
app.use(session({
    secret: 'supersecretpwd',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: expiryDate
}))
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(validator());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    app.locals.message = req.flash('message')
    app.locals.success = req.flash('success')
    app.locals.user = req.user
    next();
  });
```

I do not really know what more code should I provide, but I can provide more implementation details.

Comment: How are you declaring variables? Using `var`?

Comment: Yes, I have checked everything and there is not a single global variable

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed

```
app.locals.user = req.user
```

to:

```
res.locals.user = req.user
```

And the concurrency problem dissappeared.

I wish anybody could explain why this worked in order to elaborate a better answer.

Comment: This happens because app.locals is shared for each request-response. Meanwhile res.locals only lives in the context of each single request-response.

Answer (score 0):

Williams,
I have the same issue and i found this useful reply that may clarify our doubts:

"You can consider app.locals to be global. Some examples of things you might want to store in app.locals: URL helpers, application-level constants. You should put anything here that you want accessible in every single view.

res.locals stores data only for a particular response (which responds to a particular request). For example, GET /something will create a new res.locals that gets passed through all the middleware responding to '/something.' Appropriate information here is stuff like authenticated user details from your question.

The lifecycle looks like this, where your responsibilities are bold (everything else is done for you by express):

- app is created (var app = express();)
- app.locals is created
- request arrives
- res.locals is created for that request
- you add things to res.locals like user roles (res.locals.role = 'admin';)
- you serve a response to the request (res.render('some/view');)
- res.locals for that request is garbage collected, gone
- app.locals continues to exist as long as the app exists
  "

I know it was several months ago but it could help someone else